# Using Tika for Excel data extraction, getting Tesseract.exe not found error. Not using OCR

Tags: java, ocr, apache-tika

*This is my first question, so apologies if it's missing anything.*

I am using a product called ACCELQ and importing my own Java code using user extensions to create a custom ACCELQ command.  When doing this only the *.java program is submitted to the user extensions.  I'm using Tika to accomplish this.

- Everything works smoothly on my local machine. I get the expected string of values I expect to see.
- I create a runnable jar file and I can use this by running from a command line in ACCELQ.  Problem is it's super slow and a user extension is the way to speed it up.
- I've created the Java code to execute, there is no OCR needed, this is just for an Excel file raw data extraction. (long story but this is the only option POI doesn't work for opening the file).
- Creating the java code, I used the Tika-app.jar (2.4.1)

**The problem:**  When running from ACCELQ I get this error:

> org.apache.tika.parser.external.ExternalParser - exception trying to run  tesseract.exe
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "tesseract.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.

The tesseract.exe file is not on my local machine that I can see (unless it's here by default somewhere I don't know).  If this was wrapped in the Tika-app API then ACCELQ would have it too, so I don't believe it is there.

I've scoured the web and basically I'm trying to find how to not have OCR engaged.  From what I can read it needs the Tesseract.exe file installed regardless if you want to turn it off/on?  Not sure if this is true.

**So my ask is this:**

- Can I do this without installing Tesseract.exe?  If so how do I avoid this error.
- If I absolutely have to install this, then where does the file need to reside?

  - I still need to disengage OCR so how to do this so it runs optimally?

I'm trying to keep this basic program light and fast as possible without having to load a bunch of unnecessary things.

**What I've tried**

- I've basically combed through the Apache site here:  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/tika/tikaocr
- I cannot use Maven since this is only using one *.java file that needs to be formatted a certain way for ACCELQ to pull into their commands.
- I've tried using the Parser and Facade route with Tika, but it still tries to use tesseract.exe. it errors at

  - Facade:  `content = tika.parseToString(is);`
  - Parser:  `Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();`

```java
TesseractOCRConfig config = new TesseractOCRConfig();
config.setSkipOcr(true);
ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
context.set(TesseractOCRConfig.class, config);

Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
parser.parse(inputStream, handler, metadata, context);
```

- The following 2 methods are the ones I've tried and both give errors at the parser line.

```java
private static String extractContentUsingParser(InputStream is) {
    BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();

    try {
        ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
        parser.parse(is, handler, metadata, context);
    } catch (IOException | TikaException | SAXException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR extractContentUsingParser routine:  Tika parse caused an error");
    }
    return handler.toString();
}
    
public static String extractContentUsingFacade(InputStream is) {
    Tika tika = new Tika();
    String content = "";
    try {
        content = tika.parseToString(is);
    } catch (IOException | TikaException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR extractContentUsingFacade routine:  Tika parse caused an error");
    }
    return content;
}
```

Comment: Can you pass in a Tika Config XML file?

Comment: I don't use one due to the ACCELQ integration

Comment: Are you able to create your own `TikaConfig` object, or does your framework give you that too? (Sorry, I know Tika, never heard of ACCELQ....)

Comment: Yes I believe I could use a TikaConfig.  I may be mistaken, but it seemed like it was still looking for the tesseract.exe.  If it doesn't it sounds like that may be my only solution.